# <th> element is using more than expected width because of <span> inside of it

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a table and inside the  elements I'm rendering a  with and  inside, based on if that column is sortable or not. The problem I'm running into is that the  that contain the  are using much more width than the ones that do not when the  is like 15px wide.

Here's a draft of my code.

```css
.table{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.table thead{
  position: relative;
}

.table th{
  font-size: .9rem;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}

.table th span{
  margin-left: .4rem;
}

.table th span svg{
  width: 1rem;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>       // This th has too much width
     thead1
     <span>
      <svg>...</svg>
     </span>
    </th>

  <th>thead2</th>  // This th is ok.
   </tr>
  
  

</thead>
</table>
```

I'm expecting `table` to span the full width of it's parent element and the `<th>` elements to have an unset width each using a somewhat consistent space.

[This is what my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d55Ho.png)

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpohE.png)

I have tried to set `table-layout: fixed` and that solved the issue but I don't really want my columns to have a fixed width.

I have tried to do some regular manipulation with css like adding `display: flex` to the parent and `flex-grow: 1` for the  elements, but that makes everything worse.

I'm pretty lost here...

Comment: You set your ```.table``` class to ```width: 100%;```  so I think that's the reason why the your table force the *th* to stretch to meet that 100% width.

Comment: @Newbee but why specifically on those elements?. Also, setting any width in the `.table` element has the same effect. What do you suggest to have the table to span the entire width and not have those `<th>` elements to stretch?

Comment: Can you show an sample image of the output you want to achive?

Comment: Just added to the post.

Comment: Meaning, you want them equally and fixed width? So if you have 2 or 6 header, all them have same size of width? Is that it?

Comment: The example is not fixed width. I want them to equally occupy the width of the table, unless a `<th>` or `<td>` needs more space. Just the default behavior before everything ruins because of adding a harmless `<span>`. When there is no need for space I don't see why the columns that have the `<span>` need to use 1.5x the space they normally do.

Comment: Just in case, can you check this [image](https://i.imgur.com/ceRpbeX.png)

Comment: that's indeed what I need

Comment: I add an answer @belowaveragedev.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the css width to solve it:

and you should use tr also

```
     <table class="table">
 <thead>
<tr>
  <th style="width:50%;">
   thead1
   <span>
    <svg>
    </svg>
   </span>
  </th>

  <th style="width:50%;">thead2</th>
</tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Edited the post. I need unset width on the `<th>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add `table-layout: auto;` in your table style.

Then, since the `svg` tag create an space even you didn't set up the style, you need to set it's `width:0;` and add `min-width:100%;` So your `svg` tag now have no *margin* or *padding*.

Set up the width and height of your svg with `rect`.

Here, I made these samples and hoping it can help you in some ways.

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;
} 
tr, th, td{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
svg{
  display: block;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<h1> Table 1 </h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>  
        thead1 // This th has too much width
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="darkred"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>thead2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
  
<h1> Table 2 </h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        thead1
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="darkblue"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>thead2  // This th2 is now the bigger width.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
  
<h1> Table 3 </h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        thead1 // See, this th1 and th2 is now equal.
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="darkgreen"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>
        thead2 // Yes, even th1 have span and svg.
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

<h1> Table 4 </h1>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        thead1
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="darkgreen"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>
        thead2
      </th>
      <th>
        thead3
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="purple"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>
        thead4
      </th>
      <th>
        thead5
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="black"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
      <th>
        thead6
        <span>
          <svg height="1rem">
            <rect x="0%" y="25%" width="100%" height="50%" fill="gray"/>
          </svg>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content 1</td>
      <td>Content 2</td>
      <td>Content 3</td>
      <td>Content 4</td>
      <td>Content 5</td>
      <td>Content 6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```